# FFmpeg ios sample code for video streaming

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have done with `Video Encoding` using `AVFoundation` framework in ios.

Now i want to stream these video to a `RTMP` server using `FFMPEG`.
IT would be great help if anyone of you post a link / sample Code for achieving this.
Any other Solution other than this is also invited.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: you want to use the binary "ffmpeg" or libav* libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some [sample code](https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmovie) to get you started.

Comment: Hell0 the above example is just abt recieving a video from a server not streaming a video to a server

Comment: And Sorry, Thank You for the Reply :)