# Can't stream/play audio files in iOS recorded from Android

Tags: android, ios, audio-streaming, audio-recording, playing

I'm streaming audio(.mp4) using `StreamingKit` in objective C(recorded in iPhone).  It is streaming fine while playing audio from iPhone. However, when I receive an audio file recorded in android device(Samsung galaxy S4 & S5) it doesn't stream in iPhone and throws error: `STKAudioPlayerErrorStreamParseBytesFailed`
Later on, I tried it with different android device(Nexus 5) and it streamed fine in iPhone. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried ffmpeg lib?

Comment: @Vyacheslav No, I didn't use ffmpeg lib. I'm using steamingKit for streaming.

Comment: I do not know all detailes but, imho, it seems your framework does not support some codecs. I would suggest to use ffmpeg instead.

Comment: @Vyacheslav Any tutorial or sample code for using ffmpeg in iOS? I have tried few things but its not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23357230/1979882 ?